# Django models: how to manage field flags

Tags: django, django-models, django-profiles

I need to create a User Profile. To ensure privacy many fields in this profile will be "hidable": every User will be able to hide these information.

I can use https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield, but i would like to know if it's possibile to better tie each field to its own flag.

Answer (score 1):

Packing bits into a single field makes it more difficult to index and query the field. It's more effort than it's worth.

Comment: you're right, but i use these flags only to display the content. So i don't need to query on flags